# How to add into a singular number when pressing different buttons

Tags: c#

The title was properly written wrong but i will explain currently i have 2 sets of three buttons linked to a label. when i press a button it will place a number in the label as a result what i want to do is after the first button is pressed and then a second  is clicked i want the two scores to add together to make a total result in the label eg if i press "three of a kind" which equals 3 points then press "four of a kind" which equals 6 points i want a result of 9 in the label and then if i press "five of a kind" which equals 12 point the label would then read   18 ect can i get any help please there isnt any code to put in due to not finding anything i will put in how my buttons are linked to my labels.

Result

public class Result
        {

```
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String add = (Convert.ToInt32(3)).ToString();
        label6.Text = Convert.ToString(add);
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String add = (Convert.ToInt32(3)).ToString();
        label7.Text = Convert.ToString(add);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String add = (Convert.ToInt32(5)).ToString();
        label6.Text = Convert.ToString(add);
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String add = (Convert.ToInt32(5)).ToString();
        label7.Text = Convert.ToString(add);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String add = (Convert.ToInt32(12)).ToString();
        label6.Text = Convert.ToString(add);
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String add = (Convert.ToInt32(12)).ToString();
        label7.Text = Convert.ToString(add);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just keep 2 integer totals that you assign to the labels? In the click event add to the total & then assign the string conversion to the label?

Comment: How would one do that as i am still new to this c# coding stuff and im up for learning

Comment: This is really very basic stuff - if you need this explaining then I recommend that you get some books on programming and start from the beginning. You declare a global variable & initialise it to zero - _int label6Total = 0;_ in you click event you just add to the total & assign the result to the label - _label6Total+=3; label6.Text = label6Total.ToString();_ For common code, then you can use methods as the other two answerers have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the question, but I would suggest you to read about WPF and the MVVM mechanism to sync the data between the UI and the data.

What you're doing is writing a lot of code-behind code that is duplicated over and over and is doing a lot of unnecessary work (you convert a number to Int, then convert the result to string and then convert it again to string)

This function can be used to do the work property and efficiently once:

```
private void UpdateLabelText(Label label, int number) {
      label.Text = number.ToString();
}
```

And use this method whenever you need to update the text in your label.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the value of `label.Text` to `int` then add the value and then recast to string:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddToLabel(label7, 12);
}

void AddToLabel(Label label, int value)
{
    var n = int.Parse(label.Text); // convert the actual value of label.Text to int
    var add = n + value; // add the increment

    label.Text = add.ToString(); // assign to label.Text
}
```

Comment: Hi I have just tried and it dosnt like it have i missed anything                                         private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddToLabel(Label, 12);
        }

        void AddToLabel(Label, int 0);
        {
            var n = int.Parse(label7.Text);
            var add = n + 5;

        label7.Text = add.ToString() 
        }

Comment: Should be _AddToLabel(label7,12);_ in the click event.